# Column not found: Unknown column using Model reference but work with object reference laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, model, laravel-validation, laravel-6

I am updating my user table with validations in controller. I have created the same validation for two tables in the same controller.
When I use this code:
`User::where('id',$data->user_id)->update($this->validateField($data->user_id));` 

it show

> Error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'address_name'

Which is right because user table does not have column "address_name" but its works with this code without any error

`$user = User::where("id",$data->user_id)->firstOrFail();
$user->update($this->validateField($data->user_id));`

**What is different between these two codes, why does its not work (show unknown column Error) and why it worked without column Error?**

Here is my validateField method

```
public function validateField($id)
{
  return request()->validate([
        'address_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'mobile' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:10,13',
        'land_line' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:10,13',
        'min_order' => 'required',
        'payment_method' => 'required',
        'open_time' => 'required',
        'close_time' => 'required',
        'address'=>'required|string|max:255',
        'city'=>'required|string|max:255',
        'country'=>'required|string|max:255',
        'is_active' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$id.',id,deleted,0',
        'password' => 'sometimes|required|min:8',

     ]);
}
```

my user table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->tinyInteger('user_role')->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('is_active')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->datetime('last_login')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('deleted')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable();
        $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();

    });
```

Comment: sure that firstOrFail is not failing?

Comment: yes, it is not failing. just wanted to know the difference. Well explained. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well

```php
User::where('id',$data->user_id)->update($this->validateField($data->user_id));
```

this will update all the records that correspond to the `where` with the fields passed as parameter to the `update` function, it's just a case that the `where` will have just one match (because you are applying the where clause to the primary key), if there were more than one match, all the records will be update.
Keep in mind that the `where` function will return a `Builder`, and so the `update` function is the `update` of the class `Builder`: it means that there will be only one query (`update ... set ... where id = /*your id*/`).

This instead

```php
User::where("id",$data->user_id)->firstOrFail()->update($this->validateField($data->user_id))
```

will first get the first Record that match the `where` clause, so there will be a Query like `select ..  from ..  where id= /*your id*/`, than on that `Model` will be called the `update` function, so the function invoked here id the `Model -> update` function, where previously was `Builder -> update`, and so there will be a second query with the update.

The different behavior is caused by the different implementation of the `update` function in the two classes. Actually, on my server, both the methods will throw an error if some fields inside the array passed to `update` aren't table fields, don't know why on your the first one works fine